# .htaccess priority between directives - return a 404 for missing static resources

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

On a WordPress installation, I want to immediately return a 404 (without a courtesy page) for missing static resources, but the directives seems to conflict.

Can you help me to understand solve the issue?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(css|js|html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|swf|tar|tif|tiff|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ [nocase,redirect=404,last]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(wordpress_logged_in).*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/cache/swift-performance/([^/]*)/assetproxy
RewriteCond /home/217146.cloudwaysapps.com/ssytsarbtn/public_html/wp-content/cache/swift-performance/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/desktop/unauthenticated/index.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) wp-content/cache/swift-performance/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/desktop/unauthenticated/index.html [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule \.(css|js|html|htm|...<etc>...|zip)$ [nocase,redirect=404,last]
> ```

You are missing the *substitition* (second) argument on the `RewriteRule`. This will end up rewriting the request to `[nocase,redirect=404,last]` (a nonsensical URL) which will be routed through WordPress and ultimately WordPress will generate the 404 (which is what I assume you are referring to when you say "courtesy page").

It should be of the form:

```
RewriteRule \.(css|js|html|htm|...<etc>...|zip)$ - [nocase,redirect=404,last]
```

Note the additional hyphen (`-`) as the second argument, before the *flags* (third argument).

**UPDATE:** When you specify a non-3xx status with the `R` flag, the *substitution string* is ignored anyway. However, the `-` (hyphen) explicitly indicates "no substitution". [From the Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> `-` (dash)
>   A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path.

<sup>(The docs refer to it as a "dash", although it is strictly a *hyphen*.)</sup>

Comment: What does - stands for?

Comment: The "-" stands for "no substitution". I've updated my answer.